# integrate Firebase without cocoa No such module 'Firebase'?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

i am trying to integrate `Firebase` without using `Cocoapods` , after following the steps in readme file , i've ended up with with `No such module 'Firebase'` when i import Firebase.

The following libraries i've added to link with binary :
[image]

[image]

in Objc bridging header `#import "Firebase.h"`

at readme file they mentioned to copy the `module.modulemap` inside my project file , its my first time dealing with static libraries and `module.modulemap` , is there is a specific place should i add `module.modulemap` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `module.modulemap` can be copied anywhere in the project as long as its path is added to the `User Header Search Paths` Build Setting.

Comment: i did added the header search paths, and still same issue